# how to use a form in each template?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a search bar in my navbar and and for the management of the search bar, I don't want to manage it in the controllers of each route.

Here is my SearchForm :

```
class SearchForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('q', TextType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Rechercher...',
                    'class' => 'form-control searchBar'
                ]
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => SearchData::class,
            'method' => 'GET',
            'crsf_protection' => false
        ]);
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

In my _navbar.html.twig :

```
<li class="d-flex align-items-center nav-link-bordure-gauche">
   {{ form_start(formSearch) }}
   {{ form_end(formSearch) }}
</li>
```

And when I go on a random page of my website, I got "Variable "formSearch" does not exist."

So my question is : How can I use my form in each template ?

Thank you in advance and have a good day !

Comment: Add `formSearch` as a global or retrieve it through a custom `Twig\Function`

Comment: How do you manage the rest of the navbar? In every controller? Why not manage the SearchForm there, too?

Comment: I use globals @hakre

Comment: maybe this can help you https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#embedding-controllers

Comment: The class `SearchForm` isn't a controller instance